# Eclipse europa not working at first launch

Tags: eclipse, executable, exe, eclipse-europa

I was setting up eclipse europa. It is not working and I am not familiar with this. When I run the eclipse.exe file it shows me the above error. Since I couldn't copy and paste the error, I just took a screen shot of it (you can zoom and see the error. The picture is very clear). I have other eclipse versions (hilios and indigo) and they work fine. But I couldn't use the europa version. Can you guys please help me how to solve it?

I use windows 7 64 bit.
If you need any info, please let me know. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: as a sidenote, Eclipse Europa is quite old. You might consider moving to the latest release Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a Windows 64bits, you need to download the 64bits version of Eclipse Europa, and make sure you have a 64-bits JDK.
Or you can try a 32-bits with a 32bits JDK.

But here, it appears you have a mismatch between your Eclipse ("`-os = win32`") and your JDK.

Comment: I installed Java EE 6 SDK which contains both jdk and jre for windows 64. And I set the class path to point to this jdk. I hope I am not wrong. Am I? So I believe the jdk is also for 64 bit.

Comment: @matiman:  your jdk is fine then. But your current eclipse seems to be a 32bits version. You need the 64bits version for Eclipse. And I don't see any 64-bits distro for an old Eclipse like Europa (3.3): http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcpplug-developers/europawinter. So you need, if possible, a more recent Eclipse. Helios 3.6 minimum: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/r

Comment: I am now downloading Eclipse Indigo for JAVA EE developers, which is what I wanted and the latest version, I think. I will see what is going to happen. By the way on download link it says "eclipse-jee-indigo-win32-x86_64.zip" ... and I know it is for 64 bit but, what does it mean -win32 in this case? Does it mean it works for both 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: @matiman: you need the 64bits version, and its looks you have the right one : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/R/eclipse-reporting-indigo-win32-x86_64.zip. "win32-x86" is the general archtecture, but 64 is the right one.

Comment: Thank you. Solved with eclipse Indigo

Comment: How can I close this post, so that everybody knows it is solved?